# Looking back to Earth via general relativity

Tags: general-relativity, visible-light, spacetime, curvature

Based on Eddington experiment proving the effect of gravity on light, would it be conceivable that some light emitted from our sun bounce back on earth and continued in the universe. During this course, the gravity of different bodies could bind it to such a degree that the same light would be observable on earth, effectively looking into our past?

This would be somewhat related to this previous [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11940/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Observing the past](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/267508/)

Comment: Well no as the answer is based of light reflecting on an object (a mirror). My question is around the possibility of having currently photons travelling the universe that would have been curved by a gravity body (e.g. black hole or star) so much that it would travel back to earth. Effectively seeing ourselves.

Comment: After reading the second link it does answer it @JohnRennie. Thank you!